# Title for the UIAlertController is not appearing iOS 8.0

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I have updated for XCode 6.0.1, iOS 8.0 and after that used `UIAlertController` instead of `UIAlertView` but Title for the `UIAlertController` is not appearing.
For Reference see code:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"AlertView"    message:@"Please Click" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) 
{
}];

UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) 
{
    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];

[alert addAction:defaultAction];
[alert addAction:cancel];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what you're seeing? Are you not including any buttons?

Comment: FYI - you do realize that you created this `UIAlertController` as an action sheet, not as an alert view.

Answer (score 0):

What you are presenting is actually an **action sheet**, which is not equivalent to the `UIAlertView`. You should change `preferredStyle`, use **`UIAlertControllerStyleAlert`** instead **`UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`**:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"AlertView" message:@"Please Click" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now, where are the buttons? You can add for example (before *presentViewController*):

```
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
```

And then create your action to implement the `handler`.

Comment: None of this addresses the actual question - where is the title? Both action sheet and alert view can show titles.

Comment: @rmaddy Same issue is coming with both preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet as well as UIAlertControllerStyleAlert,Title is not visible
Please find the screenshots

http://screencast.com/t/nh4JwBqgllPq
http://screencast.com/t/udhbUwNVKE

Comment: Based on these screenshots, the `Alert` have a title but not a message. In `ActionSheet` have the message, not the title. Can you update your question with the full code snippet? Seems missing some information you did not tell us.